# Access Apache virtual hosts from WAN

Tags: apache

I have a few Apache virtual hosts set up. I'd like to access them from the outside. I found an article, [Port-based Apache virtual hosts](http://www.mikeraynham.co.uk/articles/port-based-apache-vhosts), that explained that you can tell each to listen on a specific port:

```
Listen 10080
<VirtualHost *:80 *:10080>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/.../public_html"
    ServerName www.foo.com
    <Directory "/Users/.../public_html">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Each would need a `Listen <unique port>` and I'd have to forward each port on my router. So the result would be:

- `http://<my ip address>:10080`
- `http://<my ip address>:10081`
- `http://<my ip address>:10082`
- etc...

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for "name based virtual hosts".